# Histogram with variable bin size

Tags: options, histograms

Suppose I have some dataset,e.g.,

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[2], 10000], 10]
```

which gives,

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

How can I change the histogram such that it has variable bin size such, e.g., the first six bins have size 1 while the last two have size 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html):

> Histogram[{Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],[Ellipsis]},bspec,hspec]
>
> bspec: {{b1,b2,b3...}}    use the bins [b1,b2),[b2,b3),...

Therefore,

```
Histogram[
 RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[3], 
  10000], {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I'm not sure how I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the lesson is to always read the "Details and Options" part of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The function `BinCounts`allows you to specify variable bin sizes.

```
BarChart[
   BinCounts[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[2],10000], {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10}}],
   BarSpacing -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]